# Bash: Is ${@:2} the same as $2?

Tags: arrays, bash, arguments

Is `${@:2`} the same as `$2` in Bash when my second argument is an array?
My script does work with `${@:2}` replaced by `$2`, but is there any downside?

Steve

Comment: What do you mean by "my second argument is an array"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the same: `"${@:2}"` is the subset of the array beginning at index 2

```
$ set -- foo bar baz
$ printf "%s\n" "$2"
bar
$ printf "%s\n" "${@:2}"
bar
baz
```